# UFT .Net Extensibility: How to pass Scripting.Dictionary to C# method?

Tags: c#, .net, vbscript, qtp, hp-uft

I'm implementing .Net Extensibility for custom object for UFT 12.
I have to pass Scripting.Dictionary from UFT to Extensibility and return it back to UFT.
This is example of extensibility usage:

```
Dim dictFilter
Set dictFilter = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
dictFilter.Add "Key", "Value"
dictFilter.Add "Key1", "Value1"

Dim resultFilter
Set resultFilter = SwfWindow("Selection").SwfTable("obj").MyMethod(dictFilter)
```

This is signature of C# method:

```
public Scripting.Dictionary MyMethod(Scripting.Dictionary filter)
```

When I run script I get error:
   `General run error.`

Please advice, your help is highly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used another collection in vbscript:

```
dim netObj    
set netObj = Createobject("System.Collections.Hashtable")
netObj.Add "Column1", "Value1"
netObj.Add "Column2", "Value2"

Set resultFilter = SwfWindow("Selection").SwfTable("obj").MyMethod
```

And in C# method I also used Hashtable